# why aforge.net cannot detect all webcam resolutions

Tags: c#, webcam, aforge

I have a webcam which can take 8 mpx(3264x2448) photos. I took pictures using windows 8 Photo application and they were all 8 mpx.

Problem

I use   *[aforge.video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f4d3c2ba-605c-f066-f969-68260ce5e141.htm)* just like the example in the link. 
But the problem is;
When I list myVideoCaptureDevice.VideoCapabilities the max resolution is something like 1240 X 1080,

why aforge cannot detect upper resolutions, while the webcam provides?

by the way snapshotCapabilities is null although I set snapshot to true which means aforge does not detect any snapshotcapability for my webcam

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you tell the webcam provides higher resolutions? Basically you can check reported DirectShow capabilities with [DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-Win32.exe](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Toolbox/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-Win32.exe) and AForge.NET is hardly expected to report anything different.

Answer (score 2):

videoCapabilities lists resolutions in which you can stream a video. snapshotCapabilities lists resolutions in which you can take a snapshot.

Comment: Yes you are right but my webcam's snapshotCapabilities is null. actually my problem is about how to use the webcam with full capabilities. I mean how to get 8 mpx picture

Comment: There may be an issue with snapshots on some webcams. Try to force the resolution. Also try examples from: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html (especially Snapshot Maker). Furthermore make sure what is the native resolution of your camera ccd. Most webcams only have 1080p or 720p and they cheat, when they make 8mp snapshots. They simply digitally resize them, which you can do too in software.